# Proving the triangular inequality for a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, equivalence-relations

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

Let $C(X)$ be the set of all Cauchy seq. on $X$ and define for $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ , $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ the following relation

$$
(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sim (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \Leftrightarrow d(x_n,y_n) \to 0 \ (n \to \infty)
$$

Let $\hat{X} = C(X) / \sim $ and prove that

$$
\hat{d}\left([(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}], [(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}]\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, y_n) \\
([(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, [(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}] \in \hat{X}
$$

is a metric on $\hat{X}$

Ideally I would say

$$
\hat{d}\left([(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}], [(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}]\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, y_n) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( d(x_n, z_n) + d(z_n, y_n) \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, z_n) + \lim_{n \to \infty} d(z_n, y_n) = \hat{d}\left([(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}], [(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}]\right) + \hat{d}\left([(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}], [(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}]\right)
$$
But I need help verifying the above steps, is it safe to assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, y_n)$ exists?

EDIT

I realised it follows from that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

Comment: "Is it safe to assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(x_n,y_n)$ exists?" You would have to justify it using the fact that $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are both Cauchy. Clearly, if they are not Cauchy, the limit could be infinite. (Just take $x_n=n$ and $y_n=-n$)

Comment: I'm thinking there can be a cachy seq with limit Point outside of $X$, since $X$ is not necessarily complete. @Maryam